# Нужны ли в данном предложении знаки препинания: тире и запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: "*Срок следствия продлевался неоднократно, последний раз — 01.01.2019, руководителем следственного органа*", — нужно ли тире перед датой, а также нужна ли запятая после даты?

Answer (score 1):

*Срок следствия продлевался неоднократно, последний раз - 01.01.2019 руководителем следственного органа.*

Тире можно оставить на месте отсутствующего сказуемого ПРОДЛЕВАЛСЯ.

Запятую ставить не нужно: продлевался КОГДА? КЕМ? Второстепенные члены - обстоятельство и дополнение - разные, поэтому не являются уточняющими или однородными.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант записи:

***Срок следствия продлевался неоднократно — последний раз 01.01.2019 руководителем следственного органа.***

С помощью тире обособлена поясняющая присоединительная конструкция (когда и кем продлевался).